# How do I filter rows based on values in other rows in Python?

Tags: pandas

I essentially have a data-set similar to the one below but much larger. Each row refers to a shot taken in a football match, and the data-frame contains lots of different matches combined (referred to by `Match_ID`).

I want to filter shots that have taken place up to 30 minutes after a `Goal` but in the same match. So I want to keep rows that for the same `Match_ID` have a `shot_outcome` of goal in a minute less than 30 minutes before the current row.

But I want this for all `Match_ID`'s across the whole data-set. So here, I would like to keep row 3 and row 6. How would I do this?

| Index | Match_ID | Minute | Shot_Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3857257 | 3 | Blocked |
| 1 | 3857257 | 23 | Goal |
| 2 | 4857254 | 30 | Goal |
| 3 | 4857254 | 45 | Off T |
| 4 | 4857254 | 89 | Saved |
| 5 | 6789234 | 34 | Goal |
| 6 | 6789234 | 47 | Goal |

I am pretty new to Python, so I have no real idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably much more efficient ways to solve this, but here's one solution:

#### example data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(234)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': np.random.choice(list(range(50)), size= 500, replace=True)
    , 'time': np.random.randint(1, 90, size= 500)
    , 'action': np.random.choice(['Goal', 'Blocked', 'Save'], size= 500, replace=True
                                 , p= [0.05, 0.5, 0.45])
})
```

#### Code

```
def shot_filter(df, interval=29):
    """
    For the input `df`, filter for goals + non-goal actions that occur w/in `interval` of the
    goal's time
    Return the subset
    """
    df.sort_values(by='time', inplace=True)
    actions = df['action'].tolist()
    ts = df['time'].tolist()
    idx = []
    i, goal, goal_time = 0, False, None
    while i < df.shape[0]:
        if goal and ts[i] < goal_time + interval and actions[i] != 'Goal':
            idx.append(i)
        elif actions[i] == 'Goal':
            idx.append(i)
            goal = True
            goal_time = ts[i]
        i += 1
    return df.iloc[idx, :]

# Apply per match ID
subset = []
for j in np.unique(df['ID']):
    sub_df = df.loc[df['ID'] == j].copy(deep=True)
    sub_df = shot_filter(sub_df, 29)
    subset.append(sub_df)

subset = pd.concat(subset)
```

#### cheap but incomplete verification

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(df['action'])
# Counter({'Blocked': 254, 'Save': 224, 'Goal': 22})

Counter(subset['action'])
# Counter({'Blocked': 35, 'Save': 27, 'Goal': 22})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If I included another variable in the data-set called, possession_team, which referred to which team took each shot. Would it be an easy change to restrict the filter to return shots that took place within 30 minutes of the goal, but only for the team that scored the goal?

Comment: Yes that's an easy change

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified code that should meet your expectations. Hope this helps :)

Input data

|  | Match_ID | Minute | Shot_Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3857257 | 3 | Blocked |
| 1 | 3857257 | 23 | Goal |
| 2 | 4857254 | 30 | Goal |
| 3 | 4857254 | 45 | Off T |
| 4 | 4857254 | 89 | Saved |
| 5 | 6789234 | 34 | Goal |
| 6 | 6789234 | 47 | Goal |
| 7 | 6789234 | 49 | Goal |
| 8 | 6789234 | 67 | Goal |

Code

```
# Get the Matches unique IDs
unique_ID = df['Match_ID'].unique()
# Create an empty list to store the indices of the shots that have taken place up to 30 minutes after a Goal but in the same match
indices_list = []

# For each unique Match...
for ID in unique_ID:
    # ... Create a subset of the DataFrame
    df_ID = df[df['Match_ID']==ID]
    # If a Goal is scored during the match and at least two shots have been registered
    if len(df_ID)>1 and 'Goal' in df_ID['Shot_Outcome'].values:
        # Create a subset of the match shots where Shot_Outcome == "Goal"
        df_goal_subset = df_ID[df_ID['Shot_Outcome']=='Goal']
        # Loop through each goal in the subset and add all shots within 30 minutes to the indices_list
        for _, row in df_goal_subset.iterrows():
            earliest_goal = row['Minute']
            filtered_df = df_ID[(df_ID['Minute']>earliest_goal) & (df_ID['Minute'] <= (earliest_goal + 30))]
            indices_list.extend(list(filtered_df.index))

# Filter the original DataFrame on the indices of the shots that have taken place up to 30 minutes after a Goal but in the same match
df[df.index.isin(indices_list)]
```

Output

|  | Match_ID | Minute | Shot_Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4857254 | 45 | Off T |
| 6 | 6789234 | 47 | Goal |
| 7 | 6789234 | 49 | Goal |
| 8 | 6789234 | 67 | Goal |

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your help. How would you adjust this to include all shots after 30 mins of each goal that occured in a game rather than just the first one?

Comment: Hi, I just edited the code to include all shots that occur within 30 minutes after a goal in the same match. :)

Answer (score 0):

given your input DataFrame (assigned to `input_df`):

```py
df_list = []

for id in set(input_df["Match_ID"]):
    filtered_df = input_df[input_df["Match_ID"] == id].sort_values("Minute")

    if len(filtered_df) > 1 and "Goal" in set(filtered_df["Shot_Outcome"]):
        minute_of_earliest_goal = filtered_df[filtered_df["Shot_Outcome"] == "Goal"][
            "Minute"
        ].min()
        max_minute_mark = 30 + minute_of_earliest_goal
        minutes_mask = (filtered_df["Minute"] > minute_of_earliest_goal) & (
            filtered_df["Minute"] < max_minute_mark
        )
        temp_df = filtered_df[minutes_mask]
        if not temp_df.empty:
            df_list.append(temp_df)

res_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

`res_df` will display the following:

| Index | Match_ID | Minute | Shot_Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4857254 | 45 | Off T |
| 6 | 6789234 | 47 | Goal |

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
df = df.sort_values('Shot_Outcome',key = lambda x: x.ne('Goal')).sort_values('Minute',kind='mergesort')

(df.loc[(df.groupby(['Match_ID',
                     df['Shot_Outcome'].eq('Goal').groupby(df['Match_ID']).cumsum().loc[lambda x: x.gt(0)]])['Minute'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().cumsum()).le(30)) | 
                     df['Shot_Outcome'].eq('Goal')]
                     .sort_values(['Match_ID','Minute']))
```